# getting the entire file code on the page while using include/ include_once/ require_once

Tags: php, jquery

While using include / include_once / require_once of the form `include 'filename.js';`

I get the entire code of the file displaying on the page. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show your code? Most likely you're trying to include a javascript file. include and require are for PHP files. If you want to include a javascript file you need to do it in your HTML source with a script tag

Comment: are you including filename.js inside of your PHP script?  You should include a bit more context around the code in question.  Edit: yeah, what Cfreak said.

Comment: yes , it is a jquery file that i am trying to include. Should i use <script type="text/javascript" src="location"></script> instead?

Answer (score 1):

The included file has the text at the global level in the script. If you want the text to only be output on demand then you will need to put it inside a PHP function, and then call that function when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include a javascript file within the PHP script.  You can embed it within an inline  in the page, or more appropriately, you should have the following in your PHP (as part of the HEAD section of your returned page) so the client retrieves the JS file separately:

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"".$js."\"></script>\n";
```

Where $js is a variable pointing to the script URL.

Comment: If i use 'code' <script type="text/javascript" src="location"></script> 'code' in the head section of the page will that be the same?

Comment: No, there are several differences.  If you do this, use something like get_file_contents rather than require in php.  However, you run into issues with escaping special characters that will give you problems.  It's also less overhead on browsers that can cache the JS if they load the file separately.

Comment: I may be misreading what you were asking in the above comment.  If you were just asking if you can take out the language part of the script tag, the answer is maybe, it depends on the browser, so I just leave it in to cover all my bases.  If you were asking about putting the script itself within the header, then I'd avoid doing that, though it's possible to get that to work too.